# Magento 2 Add New Customer - The customer email is missing. Enter and try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1

I am attempting to Add New Customer via the admin panel but there is no email address field nor any address details (See screenshot attached).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Rob

[image]

Comment: i have same issue,if you have idea now then help me

Answer (score 0):

Here this tutorial is showing Email field in their screenshot, you may check if it may be helpful.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-create.html
[image]

**Edited Below - added one more link to set settings**

This is the place where you can set, if you want to capture the Email or not.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-options-new.html

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. If you look at my screenshot, you will see that the email field and the Address menu item under CUSTOMER INFORMATION are missing. I am trying to add customers from within the Admin area, not the front end.